# Why using IN(...) when selecting on indexed fields, will kill the performance of SELECT query?

Tags: mysql

> Avoid using IN(...) when selecting on indexed fields, It will kill the performance of SELECT query.

I found this here: https://wikis.oracle.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27263381

Can you explain it? Why that will kill performance? And what should I use instead of IN. "OR" statement maybe?

Answer (score 3):

To tell the truth, that statement contradicts to many hints that I have read in books and articles on MySQL.

Here is an example: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/01/09/getting-around-optimizer-limitations-with-an-in-list/

Moreover, [expr IN(value, ...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) itself has additional enhancements for dealing with large value lists, since it is supposed to be used as a useful alternative to certain `range` queries:

> If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a binary search. This means IN is very quick if the IN value list consists entirely of constants.

Still overusing INs may result in slow queries. Some cases are noted in [the article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

Answer (score 2):

Because MySQL can't optimize it.

Here is an example:

```
explain select * from keywordmaster where id in (1, 567899);
```

[plan](http://pastebin.com/1ejzVMHR) (sorry for external link. Doesn't show correctly here)

here is another query:

```
   explain 
   select * from table where id = 1
   union
   select * from keywordmaster where id = 567899
```

[plan](http://pastebin.com/q6Ph2sra)

As you can see in the second query we get `ref` as `const` and `type` is const instead of range. MySQL can't optimize range scans.

Comment: nevertheless, the second query seems to take longer, at least, on my datasets.

Comment: @newtover this applies only 'when selecting on indexed fields'

Comment: I also looked into http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/0596101716, and it states: "EXPLAIN’s output can sometimes make it hard to tell whether MySQL is really looking for a range of values, or for a list of values. ... We’re not just being picky: these two kinds of index accesses perform differently. The range condition makes MySQL ignore any further columns in the index, but the multiple equality condition doesn’t have that limitation."

Answer (score 0):

[Prior to MySQL 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222630/can-mysql-use-multiple-indexes-for-a-single-query) it seems that mySQL would only use a single index for a table. So, if you had a `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (a = 6 OR b = 33)` it could chooose to use either the a index or the b index, but not both. Note that it says fields, plural.  I suspect the advice comes from that time and the work-around was to union the OR results, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (a = 6)
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (b = 33)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe IN is treated the same as a group of ORs, so using ORs won't help.

An alternative is to create a temporary table to hold the values of your IN-clause and then join with that temporary table in your SELECT.

For example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (v VARCHAR)

INSERT INTO temp_table  VALUES ('foo')
INSERT INTO temp_table  VALUES ('bar')

SELECT * FROM temp_table tmp, orig_table orig
WHERE temp_table.v = orig.value

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
```