# Add index when allready is primary

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

this is `myTable`

```
clientId, itemId, sellId
```

primary is on clientId and there is also `btree` index `no uniqe` on `sellId`

now i have part of very slow query

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable wl ON wl.itemId= ld.itemId and wl.clientId= @clientId
```

question is should i create here index combined for both `clientId` and `itemId` or since `clientId` is primary then only for `itemId` ?

[image]

Comment: Please show the query plan

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222630/can-mysql-use-multiple-indexes-for-a-single-query

Comment: @NevilleKuyt done ( i had to change some names)

Comment: We need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; there are some subtle issues that are not clear.

Comment: (Reopening because it is not just about multiple indexes.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is this: should I put the primary key PK of the table into a multi-column index as the last column?

If you use the **InnoDB** storage engine, the answer is **no**. Why not? InnoDB already includes the PK as part of the index.

If you don't use InnoDB -- that is, if you use MyISAM or AriaDB (in MariaDB), the answer is **yes**.

Still, you should evaluate how well the index helps your query.

Answer (score 0):

> ON wl.itemId= ld.itemId and wl.clientId= @clientId

begs for

```
INDEX(itemId, clientId) -- in either order
```

However, if either of those columns is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `wl`, then *no* index is needed, nor useful.  The PK will provide immediate access to the needed row.  The other column cannot do anything other than verify that it matches -- that is eliminate the row from the `JOIN`.

> should i create here index combined for both clientId and itemId

Yes, if neither is `UNIQUE`  (Keep in mind that the PK is 'unique'.)

> or since clientId is primary then only for itemId

Almost never will MySQL use two separate indexes.  (Keep in mind that the PK *is* an index.)